# Creating a comparator class to sort an ArrayList<Date>

Tags: java, sorting, date, arraylist

I am trying to sort the dates in an ArrayList object. To do so, I am using sort where dateList is my ArrayList object:

```
Collections.sort(dateList, new DateComparator());
```

I tried to do this using the following Comparator class:

```
class DateComparator implements Comparator {
    int compare(Object a, Object b) {
        Date x = (Date) a;
        Date y = (Date) b;

        if (x > y) {
            return 1;}
        else if (x == y) {
            return 0;}
        else if (x < y) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gave me the following errors:

1) cannot implement compare(T,T) - attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public where T extend Object declared in interface Comparator

2) bad operand types for binary operator '>' : if (x>y) {
first type: Date   second type: Date

3) bad operand types for binary operator '<' : else if (x

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: You can't use <> on dates, first of all.

Comment: why dont you convert the dates to complete miliseconds and then compare them using >,< signs if you wish, tht would be easier

Comment: change `x > y` with `x.after(y)` etc. Also, don't use `==` - use `equals`. See documentation of [*class Date*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: Your first problem is caused by not knowing how to use generics. Overall, reading the tutorial from oracle should cover all your questions http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not doing it just for fun or for the sake of learning, and if we actually are talking about `java.util.Date` and you actually want a **natural** comparison, well, you might like to know that `Date` already `implements Comparable<Date>` (see [its javadoc entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)).

Which means that, if you don't specify any `Comparator`... you'll have your expected behavior :)

Just use `Collections.sort(dateList);` and you're good. Here is the [javadoc entry for Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Comment: Though the message is of course well understood, I'm not sure what the word "precise" means in the context of the second last paragraph. Do you mean something like "specify"?

Comment: Oops! That's exactly what I meant... thank you very much for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
class DateComparator implements Comparator<Date> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dan try this

if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0)
                `System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");`
else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0)
                `System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");`
else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0)
                `System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");`

`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateComparator implements Comparator<Date>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {

        long t1 = o1.getTime();
        long t2 = o2.getTime();

        if(t1 < t2) {
            return -1; 
        } else if(t2 > t2) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The compare between Date objects is quite simple, just convert them into long value, and then compare the corresponding integers.

And what's more, java.util.Date implements java.lang.Comparable itself. So date1.compareTo(date2) will return the value you want.

A DataComparator is redundant。